# Yesterday was ok but today throws me NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

yesterday I coded an AsyncTask class that parse a jsonarray, the thing is that yesterday the app worked great, but today it doesn't

This is my activity:

```
public class NuevosEpisodios extends Activity {

String url = "http://www.horadeaventuraonline.com/appandroid/nuevo/list.php";
List<String> titulos, descripciones_c, fotos, id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.temporada);

    /***  Cambio el action bar por el mio  ***/

    //hiding default app icon
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    //displaying custom ActionBar
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.my_action_bar);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
    TextView titulo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo);
    titulo.setText("Nuevos episodios");
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descripcion_temp);
    TextView titul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombre_temp);
    titul.setText("Nuevos episodios");
    tv.setText("Aquí se listaran los nuevos episodios, los mas nuevos aparecen mas arriba");


    ConectionDetector cd = new ConectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

    if(isInternetPresent){
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }else{
        showAlertDialog(NuevosEpisodios.this, "No hay conexion",
                "Tu dispositivo no esta conectado", false);
    }
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(NuevosEpisodios.this, "",
                "Descargando informacion", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        //Creamos el cliente HTTP
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

        //Pasamos por POST la url
        HttpPost htppost = new HttpPost(url);

        //Definimos que tipo de dato nos pasan
        htppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        //Leer data del URL
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        String result = null;

        try {
            //Pedir una respuesta de la pagina
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htppost);
            //Guarda todo el contenido
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            //Obtenog el contenido
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            //Lee todo el contenido
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            //Guarda todo ahi
            StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            //Aca leemos todo
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            //Pasamos todo a result
            result = theStringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {
                //Si se guardo algo cerramos el input stream
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                } else {
                    Log.e("No funciono", "Cerrar el inputStream");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        JSONArray jsonArray;
        try {
            // Hacemos que el resultado sea un JSONObject
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            titulos = new ArrayList<String>();
            descripciones_c = new ArrayList<String>();
            id = new ArrayList<String>();
            fotos = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                id.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
                titulos.add(jsonobject.getString("title"));
                descripciones_c.add(jsonobject.getString("desc_short"));
                fotos.add("http://www.horadeaventuraonline.com/appandroid/nuevo/" + jsonobject.getString("image"));
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        int cantpx = dpToPx(60);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        /** ID **/
        String[] id_ep = new String[id.size()];
        id_ep = id.toArray(id_ep);

        /** Titulos **/
        String[] titulo_episodio = new String[titulos.size()];
        titulo_episodio = titulos.toArray(titulo_episodio);

        /** Descripciones  **/
        String[] descripcion_episodio = new String[descripciones_c.size()];
        descripcion_episodio = descripciones_c.toArray(descripcion_episodio);

        /** Fotos **/
        String[] fotos_episodio = new String[fotos.size()];
        fotos_episodio = fotos.toArray(fotos_episodio);

        CustomListNuevos adapter = new CustomListNuevos(NuevosEpisodios.this, titulo_episodio, descripcion_episodio, fotos_episodio);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setFocusable(false);
        Helper.getListViewSize(lv, cantpx);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seleccionaste episodio " + ++position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }


}
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("Intentar de vuelta", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton2("Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return px;
}
}
```

And this is my logcat (the android studio logcat doesn't work so I use monitor to get the logcat)

```
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941): Process: ger.slide, PID: 4941
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at ger.slide.NuevosEpisodios$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(NuevosEpisodios.java:186)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at ger.slide.NuevosEpisodios$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(NuevosEpisodios.java:85)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-14 16:43:56.301: E/AndroidRuntime(4941):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Mark the lines in the code which throw the errors.

Comment: The line is the 186 `String[] id_ep = new String[id.size()];`

Comment: If you're getting an error here, you must be getting another error before the NPE. Post more of your logcat.

Comment: If it throws a NPE, have you checked the value of `id`?

Comment: @user3249477 that is the only line, the other one is in the first line of the asynctask class.

Comment: @Jayanth the value is the result of a json yesterday was working

Answer (score 0):

id should be null

```
String[] id_ep = new String[id.size()];
```

You are getting NullPointerException on this line only thing that could lead that exception due to id.
If id is null, this line looks like

```
String[] id_ep = new String[null.size()];
```

Hence null pointer exception.

You can either check if that is null

```
if(id!=null)
      String[] id_ep = new String[null.size()];
```

You might want to check this line

```
        id.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
```

Comment: I tried to comment the id line but I get an error in the next line
`/** Titulos **/
            String[] titulo_episodio = new String[titulos.size()];
            titulo_episodio = titulos.toArray(titulo_episodio);`

Maybe It won't parse the json

Comment: @user3739503 You shouldn't check if `id` is null there, you should check why the method `doInBackground` won't reach the line `id = new ArrayList<String>();`. Use a debugger to follow that method step by step and see at which points it's exiting the method early.